# ::operator delete(pointer) returns the size of bytes liberated?

Tags: c++

There are some way to get the size of bytes liberated when you use ::operator delete(pointer)?

I try to search in the doc and there are a size_t parameter, but i think that is to give it the bytes that you want to free, not returns the size of bytes liberated.

Thanks!

Comment: it doesn't return anything. Where did you get that from?

Comment: Why do you think you want this information?

Comment: I cant fathom a design where this would be useful information, but why cant you just use `sizeof(type)`? the actual number of bytes allocated is implementation defined, but it will be at least that much.

Comment: For debuging and check that the memory is liberated.I supposed that it works well, but its for curiosity. I think that when you do the new call it save on metadata the size of the pointer to get it when you do the delete. Its only curiosity, if i cant do it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little late, but I learned this just today.  If you have C++14 support enabled, you'd overload `void operator delete(void*, std::size_t)`

references:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete - This lists all the possible signatures of `operator delete`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete - This lists how the delete operators are selected

Below is code I used to figure out how this works.  It compiles in Visual Studio 2017 with language support set to C++14 or higher.  HTH.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

auto test_counter_reserved_memory{ 0u };

void* operator new(std::size_t sz) {
    test_counter_reserved_memory += static_cast<unsigned int>(sz);
    return std::malloc(sz);
}

void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "Called: void operator delete(void* ptr)" << std::endl;
    std::free(ptr);
}

void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t sz) 
{
    std::cout << "Called: void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t sz)" << std::endl;
    test_counter_reserved_memory -= static_cast<unsigned int>(sz);
    std::free(ptr);
}

int main()
{
    test_counter_reserved_memory = 0u;

    {
        std::cout << "before: " << test_counter_reserved_memory << std::endl;
        auto p = std::make_unique<int>(750000);
        std::cout << "allocated: " << test_counter_reserved_memory << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "after: " << test_counter_reserved_memory << std::endl;


    // set breakpoint here to see results.
    return 0;
}
```